# snap: edit docker configuration

Tags: snap, configuration, read-only

I'd like to configure my docker daemon. To do so, I have to modify the daemon.json file, but unfortunatelly, it's on a filesystem that is mounted read-only;

```
root@shinwey:/snap/docker/current/config# ls -ltr
total 1
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 72 Jun  8 22:18 daemon.json

root@shinwey:/snap/docker/current/config# touch daemon.json 
touch: cannot touch 'daemon.json': Read-only file system

root@shinwey:/snap/docker/current/config# df .
Filesystem     1K-blocks   Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/loop3        128896 128896         0 100% /snap/docker/471
```

I tried to play with "snap get docker", as this command deals with configuration, with no success;

```
root@shinwey:/snap/docker/current/config# snap get docker 
error: snap "docker" has no configuration
```

Is there any specific "snap" command to update an application configuration ?

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 12, accepted):

https://github.com/docker-archive/docker-snap/issues/22

mentions that the daemon.json file should be in this folder :

> /var/snap/docker/current/etc/docker/daemon.json

or

> /var/snap/docker/current/config/daemon.json

to take into account the changes you then need to

```
sudo snap restart docker
```

Comment: I found it easy to get mixed up with subtle differences in the path. This command helped to see all the daemon.jsons on my machine:

```
➜ find / -name daemon.json 2> /dev/null
/var/snap/docker/2746/config/daemon.json
/var/snap/docker/2746/etc/docker/daemon.json
/var/snap/docker/2856/config/daemon.json
/snap/docker/2746/config/daemon.json
/snap/docker/2856/config/daemon.json
```